# how to hide or showing admin link

Tags: angular

I am trying to do hiding links and I already looked in the documentation and some fixing here at stack overflow but my changing of code only made matter worse. Here is the code.

AdminAuthGuardService

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
  private userService: UserService) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.appUser$
    .map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin);//the error is here
  }
}
```

auth.service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppUser } from './models/App-user';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchmap';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
    private userService : UserService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.user$=afAuth.authState;
  } 

login (){
  let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
  localStorage.setItem('returlUrl', returnUrl);

  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());

}

logout () {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  get appUser$() : Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$
  .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid))
} 
  }
```

bs -navbar component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { AppUser } from '../models/App-user';

@Component({
  selector: 'bs-navbar',
  templateUrl: './bs-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bs-navbar.component.css']
})
export class BsNavbarComponent  {
  appUser: AppUser;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { 
   auth.appUser$.subscribe(appUser=> this.appUser = appUser);//the error is here 
  }

  logout() {
  this.auth.logout();
  }

}
```

The error that I get is duplicate 
1.identifier'iterator Result ' in node_modules@types\node
2.type observable is not assignable in adminAuthguard.service
3.type angular fire object is not assignable in auth. service

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you are using Rxjs v6.
Since map is an operator, you should pipe the map operator like that

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.auth.appUser$.pipe(
      map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
   )
}
```

Same with your switch map operator

```
get appUser$() : Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
       switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid))
    )
}
```

Your switchMap import should be:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```